# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl in tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, xerces

I tried finding the question, but yet not found any link for this answer.

The issue we are facing is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:124)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:188)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:152)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:232)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:120)
at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.ParserUtils.parseXMLDocument(ParserUtils.java:115)
at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.ParserUtils.parseXMLDocument(ParserUtils.java:181)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.parseTLD(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:231)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:171)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1410)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
```

This issue seems to be not able to load xercesImpl.jar or at least not able to find the file. xercesImpl.jar is already present in /WEB-INF/lib, but it is not able to locate it on tomcat 7.

On tomcat 8, this works fine.
Any pointers to what can be done or where the probable issue lies, other than moving the lib in tomcat's lib folder.

Thanks

Amit

Comment: add `xercesImpl.jar` to `$TOMCAT_HOME\lib` directory

Comment: any other option, this works fine but it might affect other applications on that server.

Comment: You can also put the JAR in the WEB-INF/lib of the Web App.

Comment: It is already there, but somehow the class not getting loaded.

Comment: Which IDE you are using ?

Comment: Same happened to me when i was using Intellij's deploy. so, if you using an IDE for test, better to deploy packaged war file to tomcat manually

Comment: ? I am trying to run the application on tomcat. IDE is eclipse though. The issue is when deploying the webapp on the tomcat. I have not tried deploying via eclipse, was deploying mannually. i.e. copying war in webapps and starting tomcat.

Comment: @Amit did u find any solution for the above issue? I am facing the same issue now.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. We moved to tomcat 8.

Comment: Check all log files (catalina.out, localhost* etc) might give more clues.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/34149546/32453