# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, tomcat8

I am starting a java and tomcat based application. I am getting the following error.

```
Dec 08, 2015 12:04:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'maxSpareThreads' to '50' did not find a matching property.
Dec 08, 2015 12:04:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'maxSpareThreads' to '50' did not find a matching property.
Dec 08, 2015 12:04:01 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Realm'.
Dec 08, 2015 12:04:01 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Host'.
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:200)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:152)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:232)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.lifecycleEvent(JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java:431)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:124)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:188)
        ... 16 more
```

I have checked all the configuration file. Any lead is appreciated.

Comment: Check for the xerces-impl.jar on classpath

Comment: check in the `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project. Or check in the deployment configuration for your project. If you are using eclipse check the buildpath for libraries and deployment assembly section

Answer (score 0):

Got this, appears it was caused by the use of a "java agent" in the command that runs catalina `-javaagent=...` weird.  Gave us

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
```

Also sometimes gave us this:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl (Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1276)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2.run(LogFactory.java:1065)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.newFactory(LogFactory.java:1062)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:497)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm.<clinit>(DynaValidatorForm.java:97)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1131)
    ... 37 more
```

Fix: temporarily remove java agent parameter, then started up well.
Possible fix: make it so it can log to its log file (permissions)?